# Did Armenian forces leave Kalbajar region by 15 November, as specified in peace treaty?

Tags: armed-conflict, peace-treaty, azerbaijan, armenia

According to news outlets, the [peace treaty](https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/blogs/new-atlanticist/azerbaijan-armenia-peace-deal-could-be-the-diplomatic-breakthrough-the-region-needs/) between Armenia and Azerbaijan over the Upper Karabakh requires Armenian forces  to vacate previously occupied regions of Azerbaijan that are adjacent to the Upper Karabakh but are not part of it.

In particular, the Kalbajar region has to be cleared by 15 November 2020.

[image: Armenia-Azerbaijan peace deal map]
<sub>Source: [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-54324772).</sub>

It is 17 November already, and I don't see announcements about the fulfillment of the first milestone declared in the long-awaited peace treaty. Assuming that the war was going on for merely 30 years, I feel that any delay could trigger further escalation by radical factions of both sides of the conflict.

Has Armenia met the deadline by withdrawing from the Kalbajar region on time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azerbaijan agreed to extend the deadline for 10 more days. So, Armenia has until 25th November, 2020 to vacate the region.

source: https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/11/15/armenia-cedes-disputed-land-to-azerbaijan-after-peace-deal